# Element Ui + Vue JS [Column offset not working]

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

[image: Picture]

I am using Element UI for Vue js front end for my application, the problem I am facing is that when I set the offset for columns for small viewport devices it applies on the normal viewport as well.
I tried overriding the CSS for the framework

```
<el-col :xl="{span: 4, offset: 4}"
:lg="{span: 4, offset: 4}"
:md="{span: 6, offset: 6}"
:sm="{span: 16, offset: 4}">
```

Here is a [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/mmx38qxw/5493/), for reference:

Comment: Didn't get what exactly goes wrong for you. Fiddle looks to be working fine.

Comment: Check the picture I attached, all the cards should be in the same line the grid Element UI uses has 24 columns I put an offset of 4 and divided all the rest of the cards in 4 columns each that should display like `4 column space/ 4 column card *4 / 4 column space again`

Comment: @Alendorff I can repro if i make viewport wide enough

Comment: So what can I do to solve this problem? @Alendorff

Comment: @NaizamSherMalik just set props consistently for all your columns. E.g. like this (all props from first col) https://jsfiddle.net/mmx38qxw/5546/. For such scenarios better to have some const to bind though, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mmx38qxw/5550/ it will simplify template a bit and so you have less chances to make some typo. I have no better answer here, if you think that lib works wrong for you probably should try to open an issue at lib github repository.

Answer (score 0):

> the problem I am facing is that when I set the offset for columns for small viewport devices it applies on the normal viewport as well.

Set for the normal viewport offset: 0. Just tested it and it works fine